# Do short exact sequences form an abelian category?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm reading "categories for the working mathematician " of MacLane. At page 202, we define what is a morphism of short exact sequences (in an abelian category) and say that  this form the category of short exact sequences. This category is additive. My question is : is this category abelian?
First my intuition was "yes" but then I tried to prove it... Now I'm convinced that the answer is "No" because of some constructions we can not do with kernels. 
Any help? Any counterexample?

Comment: Think about the snake lemma.

Comment: This gives just the half of the solution. It is the other half which is difficult .

Comment: Although the question I linked to is different, the answer actually says explicitly that the answer to your question is no.